# How can I make conditional wait methods in a one function?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

This is the most known way to make the wait function

```
public BaseFunction(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    wait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, 30);
}

public WebElement waitUntil(By element) {
    return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element);
}
```

but I want to make a function that takes expected conditions as a parameter. I need to select whether is visibilityOfElementLocated or invisibilityOfElementLocated. I don't want to duplicate the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your `waitUntil` method to take the condition as parameter like this:

```
public WebElement waitUntil(Function<WebDriver, WebElement> condition) {
    return wait.until(condition);
}
```

Then you can call it as either

```
baseFunction.waitUntil(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
```

or

```
baseFunction.waitUntil(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(element));
```